# ExtJS window jumps to the top when selecting a tab from a tab bar

Tags: extjs

Just a quick question about tab bars in ExtJS. I have built windows with a lot of controls in and which concludes with a set of controls within each of 6 tabs in a tab bar. The controls in each tab are almost identical and I am not handling an tab changing events. When I select a tab, however, the focus returns to the top of the dialog (scrolling a fair way as it does so) and the user then has to manually scroll back down to the tab to see the controls now visible.

Does changing tabs engender a windows refesh? If it does, is there any way I can stop this happening?

I need to confess that this happening is restricted to only one of my two computers. I have installed the completed application in Azure and when I run it from machine1 in either IE or Chrome it works fine. But if I use machine2 with the same versions of IE and Chrome the jump and some strange events take place. Is there some machine dependent value that could cause the jump?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know that I found out what was happening with some further digging around. The difference between my two PC's is that the laptop has a touch screen. This causes ExtJS to add in special scrolling classes to deal with the user scrolling on the body of the dialog with his finger.

There are a couple of problems that this created for me. First, the jump to the top was caused by a reset of the scroller after switching the active tab. The reset function de-did stuff, including setting the scroll back to the top. Interestingly by switching the tab page it caused 96 scollers to be reset. I can't think why this would be the case and suspect that it is causing a full dialog refresh, rather than just the tab, which I don't see why the refresh is needed anyway. I'm looking to find a way to stop this from happening.

I mentioned some other problems above. One was that the second tab appeared empty but with scroll bars. We could use these to see the proper tab content. I found it was an Ext JS bug. Erroneously, when Ext JS activated the next tab, it placed the tab's  outside of the scrolling class (marked by x-scroll-scroller) rather than inside it. This led to it getting confused. To fix this I added some code in the getRenderTarget function of the Ext.layout.container.Container class. Previously this simply was

```
getRenderTarget: function() {
   return this.owner.getTargetEl();
}
```

I added a specific test to see if the first child was a scroller, and that being the case, returned the scroller instead.

```
getRenderTarget: function() {
   var me = this.owner;
   if (me.body && me.body.dom.firstChild.className == 'x-scroll-scroller')
      return me.body.dom.firstChild;
   return me.getTargetEl();
}
```

The parentage of the tab controls was now maintained correctly and the other strange artifacts that I briefly alluded to above disappeared.

So current state of play. I am looking for the way to stop the refesh and will update this when I find it, but the touch screen support is definitely flakey.

FYI. I am using Ext JS 6.1.